# I have a work time of 90 hours, I want to subtract hour:minutes worked to get hours:minutes left to complete work in a libreoffice spreadsheet

Tags: time, spreadsheet, libreoffice

I have set 90 hours to complete a job.
Every time I work on the job I want to subtract that time from 90 (90 - time worked)
This is to be done in a Libreoffice spreadsheet

Comment: So, just do it!? What's the problem?

Comment: I finally solved the problem by making the 90 = 90:00:00